# Number of movie of genre 'drama' by country

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection as follow,

```
[
  {
    "_id": "movie:1",
    "title": "Vertigo",
    "year": 1958,
    "genre": "drama",
    "country": "DE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "movie:2",
    "title": "Alien",
    "year": 1979,
    "genre": "Science-fiction",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  {
    "_id": "movie:3",
    "title": "Sacrifice",
    "year": 1986,
    "genre": "drama",
    "summary": null,
    "country": "FR"
  }
]
```

I have the following query,

```
db.moviesEmbedded.aggregate([
        {"$group" : {_id:{country:"$country", genre: "$genre", movie: "$title"}, movies:{$sum:1} } } ]
```

But it doesn't give me the correct output. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `$match` first to filter the desired values. So you need this query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "genre": "drama"
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$country",
    "total": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3L0WnMz0vOu).

Note that you can output the total or multiple values in this way if you prefer:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "genre": "drama"
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$country",
    "movie": {
      "$push": {
        "title": "$title",
        "year": "$year"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BTjDYiqE3SY)